# event.target.parentNode... pointing to different parents in chrome and firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

In this project am working on I have button that has and image inside it for styling purposes... I am trying to implement the functionality such that when the button is clicked I use event.target.parentNode.parentNode... a number of times to get an HTML5 data attribute(postid) from one the topmost parent divs, in Firefox I need to call parentNode 4 times and it works in Chrome it does not work I need to call parentNode 5 times, this means the two browsers are referring to different parents. I added $(event.target).parent().parent().css('border','5px solid black'); to find out which target each browser is considering. I found Chrome considers the event.target to be the image(which is what is actually clicked) but Firefox considers the button to be the event.target(which is where the event was actually attached)..... How can I make this button and its event code portable on both browsers without removing the image inside the button tag(that worked).

The code looks like

```js
$(document).on('click', '.opinion', function(event) {

  try {
    post_id =  event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
    //$(event.target).parent().parent().css('border','5px solid black');
    url = $('#opinionUrl' + post_id).val();
    token = $('#token').val();
  } catch (e) {

    alert(e);
  }
///Some more code to do stuff
});
```

```html
<button class="icon opinion">
  <img class="icon" src="{{URL::asset('assets/icons/haha.png')}}">
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why use jQuery and chain `parentNode` or `.parent()`?

`.closest()` will do the job for you https://api.jquery.com/closest/

```
post_id = $(this).closest("[data-postid]").data().postid;
```

Comment: thanks, @Roko C. Am still getting familiar with some core features of Jquery... thanks again!