# Click event in chrome vs firefox gives different targets?

Tags: javascript

**TL;DR**:

Clicking this button gives different targets on the click event if you are in Firefox vs Chrome. Seems like there should be an elegant solution to this problem instead of having to check an element's parent to see if it's a button or not.

Similar questions:

- [event.target.parentNode… pointing to different parents in chrome and firefox?](http://(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967713/event-target-parentnode-pointing-to-different-parents-in-chrome-and-firefox)[I%20don't%20want%20to%20use%20jQuery%20if%20I%20can%20help%20it].) <- I don't want to use jQuery if I can help it.

**Details**

JS:

```
    let guid = '05c4d5b0-44c6-4e4f-a4dd-b5ac9029b3a9';
    //Get the div with this GUID.
    let elem = document.getElementById(guid);

    //Get the button that belongs to this div that has the 'delete-device' class.
    let b = elem.getElementsByClassName("delete-device")[0];

    //Add listener to delete the div when clicked.
    b.addEventListener("click", delete_devices, false);
```

HTML:

```
<button data-id="05c4d5b0-44c6-4e4f-a4dd-b5ac9029b3a9" class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light red delete-device ">
      <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
</button>
```

In Firefox, e.target is the button.

In Chrome, e.target is the `<i>` element.

So, when we execute the callback (below) Chrome can't find the div we need, and sets the variable to null, which (of course) throws errors.

```
function delete_devices(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    let elem = document.getElementById(id);
    elem.remove();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `e.target`, use `this` instead.

Comment: Are you able to use a `span` instead of an `i`? `span`s do not have the same issue.

Comment: Also, you have references to an `id` that contains a GUID, but you haven't shown an element with an `id` at all. You've used `data-id`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reference `e.target`. In a DOM event handler, `this` refers to the element that triggered the event. If you set up the event handler on the button (the parent element), then the child element cannot be the trigger for the event.

Also, your code attempts to get the `id` of an element, but none of your elements has an `id` established for it. You've used `data-id`, which can be accessed via the `element.dataset.attributeName` syntax if needed.

```js
//Get the div with this GUID.
const guid = '05c4d5b0-44c6-4e4f-a4dd-b5ac9029b3a9';
const b = document.querySelector("[data-id='" + guid + "']");

// Add listener to delete the button when clicked.
b.addEventListener("click", delete_devices);

function delete_devices(e){
    this.remove();
}
```

```html
<button data-id="05c4d5b0-44c6-4e4f-a4dd-b5ac9029b3a9" 
        class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light red delete-device ">
   <i class="material-icons" id="05c4d5b0-44c6-4e4f-a4dd-b5ac9029b3a9">delete</i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` to refer to clicked element and if you're using a button, then make sure to really add the event on button and some element within it.

```js
const guid = '05c4d5b0-44c6-4e4f-a4dd-b5ac9029b3a9';
//Get the div with this GUID.
const elem = document.getElementById(guid);
const button = elem.querySelector("button.delete-device");
//Add listener to delete the div when clicked.
button.addEventListener("click", delete_devices, false);
    
function delete_devices(e){
    let id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log("Deleting widget: ", id)
    const elem = document.getElementById(id);
    elem.remove();
    return true;
}
```

```html
<div id="05c4d5b0-44c6-4e4f-a4dd-b5ac9029b3a9">Device widget
<button data-id="05c4d5b0-44c6-4e4f-a4dd-b5ac9029b3a9" type="button" class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light red delete-device ">
      <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
</button>
</div>
```

Notice that I removed **`event.preventDefault`**. I suppose you used it because you wanted to prevent form from being submitted. Any `<button>` is submit by default, to turn it to normal button do this:

```
<button type="button">This does not submit form</button>
```